# How can I draw an OKINA character in Android App

Tags: android, fonts, draw

I would like to use the Hawaiian OKINA character in my apps output. I am using the MONOSPACE typeface and printing with the drawText function. My app minSDK is 15. The text being printed originates in a text file in my raw directory. I create this file with a simple text editor.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Joni, the Okina is a special character. I don't think it is even in the monospace typeface I have available. So I need to load a special character in the middle of a string some how.

Comment: Have you tried at least? From Wikipedia: "But as of 2008, Apple Mac OS X,Microsoft Windows and Linux-based computers and all new major smartphones have no problem with the glyph"

Comment: Yeah, I read that earlier, Joni. From the point of view of using a word processor is what they are talking about.  I need to embed a special character in an ascii string is all. Somebody out there has done it and will tell me how. Thanks Joni.

Comment: Well there's your first problem: you have to use Unicode. You can't use ASCII because okina is not an ASCII character. Copy and paste the character in your text file and save it in UTF-8. If it still doesn't work post the contents of the file and the code you have for reading and displaying the data.

Comment: Ok so the unicode for this character is U+02BB, therefore, I just need to place the 02BB inside the string, where I want the okina to print, but I need some escape or delimiter code so the underlying print routine understands what it is. How do I escape or delimit this 02BB?

Comment: Copy and paste the character to a plain text file and save using UTF-8 encoding. You don't need delimiters or escape codes.

Comment: Microsoft word will let me enter the unicode character and displays it right. But to save in txt the character disappears. There is no save in UTF-8 option, only word and txt. There is no way to do it I can find in notepad, either. Can I patch it in within Android Studio to try it?

Comment: Notepad and Word are really bad as text editors for programmers. Copy and paste usually works with Android studio. Notepad++ too. If you are writing Android resource files you can use the Unicode escape code \u20bb.

Comment: thanks Joni. I set up edit pad lite 7. opened the text file and saved it as UTF-8. set the cursor where I wanted the character, opened up the character map for unicode, found the code I wanted and double clicked. saved it and placed file in raw directory. works great. so I learned you can mix unicode with plain old text, and it will be displayed properly on Android app using canvas drawtext. thanks again Joni!